# Effective Index on small table

Tags: postgresql, indexing

So this is probably a super basic question but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the return speed any faster.

Basically I have a table that currently has about 70k rows.  It has about 10 columns of text, and I write a query like this:

```
select *
from players
where playername = 'playername'
```

I currently only have one btree index on playername and it still takes about 500 ms to execute and return... Any ideas?

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query. What is your OS? How is your I/O system doing?

Comment: i know for a fact MySQL is storing TEXT datatype separated from the table data which cause a extra random disk i/o when fetching a TEXT column.. Not sure if PostgreSQL does the same but it might explain the slow fetch.  There is one qoute "Very long values are also stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid access to shorter column values." from the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html which let's me believe PostgreSQL also requires extra random disk i/o to fetch the TEXT column